# Annotated Ada language (Anna)

Tags: ada

I am a beginner on Ada language and I would like to know what notations means. I have read in Kreuger software reuse paper that Anna is a an annotation language to describe Ada. Is that consider to be a formal comment for Ada code ?

For example:

```
subtype EVEN is INTEGER;

--| where X : EVEN = ) X mod 2 = 0;
```

The 2nd line is Anna annotation for the first line which is Ada code. 
Is the 2nd line just a comment to let the user understand the first line or is it a constraint that is a "must" to mention not just an optional line?

I am really confused

Answer (score 3):

Anna is *ancient*, do not waste your time with it.

There are a number of places to get starting with Ada. Among them is the [Ada Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming), and the Ada Information Clearinghouse (AdaIC) maintains a [list of suggested resources](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

If you're interested in formal logic as it applies to Ada, you'll want to look into SPARK ("SPARK is a programming language, a set of source code analysis (static verification) tools, and a design method for developing high-assurance software.") Here's a [quick overview and tutorial](http://www.adacore.com/sparkpro/tokeneer/discovery/), though you may not want to tackle that until you've got some practice with Ada under your belt.

You probably already know about the GNAT compiler, but just in case, [GNAT GPL 2012](http://libre.adacore.com/) is an open source compiler available for Linux, Windows, and a few other platforms. (GNATPro is available for many platforms.)

Good luck, ask questions here, other resources include [comp.lang.ada](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada) and the [Ada sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ada/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I am asking for Anna because I would like to present it as an example for Annotation in my thesis. I would like to understand those 2 lines so that I can put an example because I am doing research on software reuse and Anna is an example for specifying components written in Ada

Comment: Look at the SPARK material. It does the same kind of annotation, and as it is current it is *much* easier to find explanatory material about it. (In short, ANNA is long gone, so there's little definitive material about it.)

Answer (score 3):

1. EVEN is integer with the constraint of being, well, even. So the 2nd line is a constraint. But it will not be checked by the compiler -- and, to the best of my knowledge, the Anna toolset has never been able to check such constraints.
2. Anna is ancient and long gone -- but the recent Ada standard (Ada 2012) supports such annotations (which can even be checked by the compiler). So your Ada/Anna expression could be written in Ada 2012 as

   subtype Even is Integer
   with Dynamic_Predicate => Even mod 2 = 0;

This is actually an example from the Ada 2012 rationale, see [Ada 2012](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada-2012/).